# How do you add a cookie given after a post request in C?

Tags: c, authentication, cookies, libcurl

I am trying to create a program that logs into a website for me. The problem is, when I follow the redirection the website supplies a unique cookie that I can't figure out how to add to the post request. I have been going through each of the libcurl options on the man page, but I can't find anything that will do this. So far this is the post request function that I have.

```
void webpost(char* url, char* postdata) {

    CURL *handler = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode err;
    long size = sizeof(postdata);

    if (handler) {
        curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 50L); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L); 
        curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); 
        err = curl_easy_perform(handler);
        if (err != CURLE_OK) { 
            printf("ERROR POST: %s returned (%s)\n", url, curl_easy_strerror(err));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(handler);
    }

}
```

When this function runs, I get the following result.

```
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to website.com (10.10.10.10) port 2048 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:59:50 GMT
< Server: EZproxy
< Expires: Mon, 02 Aug 1999 00:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:59:50 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: ezproxy=uRZWAo3IsKyR9O0; Path=/; Domain=.website.com
< Location: http://website.com/connect?session=suRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://website.com/connect?session=suRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Hostname website.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to website.com (10.10.10.10) port 2048 (#1)
> GET /connect?session=suRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Accept: */*

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:59:50 GMT
< Server: EZproxy
< Expires: Mon, 02 Aug 1999 00:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:59:50 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: ezproxy=uRZWAo3IsKyR9O0; Path=/; Domain=.website.com
< Location: http://website.com/connect?session=ruRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 1
* Issue another request to this URL: 'website.com/connect?session=ruRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu'
* Hostname website.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to website.com (10.10.10.10) port 2048 (#2)
> GET /connect?session=ruRZWAo3IsKyR9O0&url=menu HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Accept: */*

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:59:50 GMT
< Server: EZproxy
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: close
< 
<html>
<head>
<title>Cookie Required</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Licensing agreements for these databases require that access be extended
only to authorized users.  Once you have been validated by this system,
a "cookie" is sent to your browser as an ongoing indication of your authorization to
access these databases.  This cookie only needs to be set once during login.
</p>
<p>
If you are using a firewall or network privacy program, you may need
reconfigure it to allow cookies to be set from this server.
</p>
<p>
As you access databases, they may also use cookies.  Your ability to use those databases
may depend on whether or not you allow those cookies to be set.
</p>
<p>
To login again, click <a href="/login">here</a>.
</p>
</body>
</html>

* Closing connection 2
```

Comment: seems that curl does not send cookes by default but you may add flags for storing them into file and read that file when request is sent. see this page: https://catonmat.net/cookbooks/curl/set-cookies

Comment: you can store cookie and add in request headers

Comment: I suggest reading up on [how to use cookies with libcurl](https://ec.haxx.se/libcurl-http/libcurl-http-cookies) from *Everything curl* before continuing!

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working by saving the cookie to a file and loading it in the same request.

curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
 curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add a header in the next request to a site matching the `domain` and `path` parameters of the `Set-cookie:` header that says:

```
Cookie: ezproxy=uRZWAo3IsKyR9O0
```

That will be enough for the server to recognize and locate the session you come from, so it can locate the data belonging to your session.

You can read [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) for a description of the status management mechanism and read about the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I was able to get it working by saving the cookie to a file and loading it in the same request.

curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");